subprocess.Popen() opens image in background but only when the path contains non english characters
I am trying to write code to open an image in the windows photos app
The following python code opens an image in the photos app, but in the background i.e. no window is created but the process runs in the background indefinitely. this only occurs when a non English character is present in the path.
import subprocess

path = "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\я.jpg"
command_name = "start"
command_args = ["", path]
subprocess.Popen(
    [command_name] + command_args,
    shell=True,
    close_fds=True,
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
    | subprocess.CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB,
)


Do you get the same result when using a path that doesn’t exist?  I suspect an encoding issue

i suspected an encoding issue at first too, but it appears that was not the issue. i have found a solution to my original problem im just not too sure what the underlying cause of this is

You can answer your own question. I’d still like to know if you get the same behavior for a path that doesn’t exist.

Also on Windows, see os.startfile
